# How do you keep current, paginated-items on refresh/reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to keep the current, paginated items on the page after refresh/reload, i.e. if I were on the 2nd paginated-section, keep the data after page reload.

So far, I have the list of entries & pagination installed onto the HTML page:

```
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="blog-entry blog-post" style="display: none;"></div>

<div class="pagination-container">
 <input type="hidden" id="current">
 <input type="hidden" id="show_per_page">

 <ul class="pagination blog-pagination" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
  <li><a class="current" href="javascript:showPage(1)" longdesc="1">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="numericButton" href="javascript:showPage(2)" longdesc="2">2</a></li>
  <li><a class="numericButton" href="javascript:showPage(3)" longdesc="3">3</a></li>
  <li><a class="nextbutton" href="javascript:next()">Next »</a></li>
  <li><a class="nextbutton" href="javascript:last(3);">Last »</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The JS for the pagination:

```
makePager = function(page){
 var show_per_page = 5;
 var number_of_items = $('.blog-entry').size();
 var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items / show_per_page);
 var number_of_pages_todisplay = 5;
 var navigation_html = '';
 var current_page = page;
 var current_link = (number_of_pages_todisplay >= current_page ? 1 : number_of_pages_todisplay + 1);

 if (current_page > 1)
  current_link = current_page;

  if (current_link != 1) navigation_html += "<li><a class='nextbutton' href=\"javascript:first();\">« Start</a></li><li><a class='nextbutton' href=\"javascript:previous();\">« Prev</a></li>";

  if (current_link == number_of_pages - 1) current_link = current_link - 3;
  else if (current_link == number_of_pages) current_link = current_link - 4;
  else if (current_link > 2) current_link = current_link - 2;
  else current_link = 1;

  var pages = number_of_pages_todisplay;
  while (pages != 0) {
   if (number_of_pages < current_link) { break; }
   if (current_link >= 1)
    navigation_html += "<li><a class='" + ((current_link == current_page) ? "current" : "numericButton") + "' href=\"javascript:showPage(" + current_link + ")\" longdesc='" + current_link + "'>" + (current_link) + "</a></li>";
    current_link++;
    pages--;
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
  }

  if (number_of_pages > current_page){
   navigation_html += "<li><a class='nextbutton' href=\"javascript:next()\">Next »</a></li><li><a class='nextbutton' href=\"javascript:last(" + number_of_pages + ");\">Last »</a></li>";
  }
  $('ul.blog-pagination').html(navigation_html);
}

var pageSize = 5;
showPage = function (page) {
 $('.blog-entry').hide();
 $('#current').val(page);
 $('.blog-entry').each(function (n) {
  if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
   $(this).show();
  });
 makePager(page);
}

showPage(1);
next = function () {
 new_page = parseInt($('#current').val()) + 1;
 showPage(new_page);
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
}
last = function (number_of_pages) {
 new_page = number_of_pages;
 $('#current').val(new_page);
 showPage(new_page);
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
}
first = function () {
 var new_page = "1";
 $('#current').val(new_page);
 showPage(new_page);    
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
}
previous = function () {
 new_page = parseInt($('#current').val()) - 1;
 $('#current').val(new_page);
 showPage(new_page);
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
}
```

I understand that local/sessionStorage methods could alleviate this issue, but I am struggling on how to implement this. Any help on this would be appreciative.

**EDIT:** Uploaded a test site for a visual example. [Click here to view.](https://www.tmmtekh.com/test/) Notice how reloading the page will always take you to the first, paginated list.

Comment: Why do you want to keep this on page refresh ? maybe not reloading the page would be a better approach..?

Comment: I developed it to where the pagination will navigate you through the entire list of blog-entries. Highlighting the 2nd pagination button, for example, will take you to the next series of entries, while hiding the others. The problem is that when you attempt to refresh the page, it will automatically trace back to the 1st set of entries, rather than the 2nd. This is where I am having trouble.

Comment: You should paginate server-side and use ajax to make deeplinking/content loading/interactions on the client side. This is IMHO the smartest way of doing this.

Comment: Using any other API would be a hack

Comment: Any plugin recommendation for this server-side pagination?

Comment: I don't know anything about your server code... But if it is wordpress for example, you can set the number of post per page. However, while writing these lines, I realize that you can keep the current page in the url's hash.

Comment: Or use the history API